# Сохранение значения enum Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как можно реализовать сохранение значения типа enum в игре?

Comment: enum это int, вот

Comment: @EugeneBartosh а вот так: `enum Importance : byte
    {
        Low,
        Medium,
        High
    };` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вопрос о понимании enum, то сохраняйте (как писали в комментариях) как обычное целочисленное значение.
Если у вас сохраняется много значений (например, профиль или список состояний), вы можете создать класс SomeClass, в котором будут все нужные для сохранения поля и конвертировать его в json файл.
Старайтесь задавать более конкретный вопрос, тогда ответ будет более точным.